# Convergence radius of a power series $\sum{(n^2 \cdot \sin{\frac{2}{n^2}})^{n^2+2} \cdot x^{n^2}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

$$\sum{(n^2 \cdot \sin{\frac{2}{n^2}})^{n^2+2} \cdot x^{n^2}}$$
$\\$
The task is to find the covergence radius of this power series. Usually, I would find it as $\frac{1}{L}=R$ where $L=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\lvert \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \rvert} $ (if it exists) or $L=\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{\lvert a_n \rvert}$ , but $x^{n^2}$ is bothering me. Am I allowed to substitute $k=n^2$?

Comment: So ur looking for a_n but u got ^n^2 as exponent. Take a n-th root of a_n^2 to get a_n. Then use limsup nthsquare(a_n) formula. Use sinx/x when x-> 0 and ur done cuz ur exponent will be heading to 1.

Comment: Just a note ; R= limsup |a_n+1/a_n|  not 1/it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Write the power series in the form

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_{k} x^{k}$$
by defining
$$ a_{k} := \left(n^2\cdot \sin{\frac{2}{n^2}}\right)^{n^2+2}$$ if there is a $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $k = n^2$ and $a_k  := 0$ else.

Comment: I did that part and I know that $k $ has to be such that $k=n^2$ from the definition, but what to do next?